# How do I display one news category only in ExpressionEngine?

Tags: html, expressionengine

We use ExpressionEngine to manage our website and have latest news displayed on our website using the following code:

```
<div class="news_col">
    <h2><a href="/news">RECENT NEWS</a></h2>
    <ul class="listing clearfix news">
        {exp:channel:entries site="not moo" channel="not moo" entry_id="{exp:n_categories:get_news_bsuk frontpage='TRUE'}" orderby="date" paginate="bottom" limit="5" dynamic="no" parse="inward"}
        <li class="clearfix">
            <p class="date">{entry_date format="%j"}<br />{entry_date format="%M"}</p>
            <div>
                <p{if sticky=='y'} class="sticky"{/if}>
                    <a href="{url_title_path="/news/view"}">{title}</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    </ul>
</div><!--/news_col-->
```

When creating a news entry we have a list of related content categories we can select and what I would like to do is create another news column on our homepage that just displays news that has one of those related content categories selected.

What do I need to change or add to that code to just get one sub-category displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually managed to figure this out now using this line of code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" category_group="2" category="161" orderby="date" paginate="bottom" limit="5" dynamic="no" parse="inward"}
```

I'm sure I tried this before but obviously made some change without realising it but I'm now get a news column displaying entries from just one news sub-category.